# Find option text with wildcard jquery

Tags: jquery, html

Trying to get the value `3`, What am I doing wrong with my jQuery?

**jQuery:**

```
$('select[name="clauses"]').find("option[text~='OR']").val()
```

**HTML:**

```
<select multiple=""  name="clauses" >
    <option value="0"> </option>
    <option value="1">       (  </option>
    <option value="2">         (  Someone</option>
    <option value="3">    OR Something ) )</option>
    <option value="4">AND Something</option>
</select>
```

I used `~` because it might be the case I need to find the word Someone for example.

**EDIT:** Thank you all for your fast responses. Unfortunately I'll have to mark answered only 1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery doesn't have `text` selector, apart from that `text` is not an attribute, you can use `:contains` selector:

```
$('select[name="clauses"]').find("option:contains('OR')").val();
```

Comment: It used to work in old versions (1.6 and before) of jQuery though it seems - http://jsfiddle.net/B32A9/

Answer (score 2):

`text` isn't an attribute, so you can't use an attribute selector on it. You can use `contains` instead:

```
$('select[name="clauses"]').find("option:contains('OR')").val()
```

This won't handle cases like `DOOR`. If you need to do that, use a regex with `filter`:

```
$('select[name="clauses"]').find('option').filter(function() {
    return $(this).text().match(/\bOR\b/);
}).val();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your approach assumes the `<option>` elements have a `text` attribute, which is not the case, what you're looking for is the `:contains()` selector, as you can see on [jQuery's documentation](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/):

> Description: Select all elements that contain the specified text.

So try with:

```
$('select[name="clauses"]').children('option:contains(OR)').val();
```

Also keep in mind the `<option>` elements are direct children of the `<select>` so there's no need to use `.find()` in this case...

**[JSBin Demo](http://jsbin.com/eloquy/1/edit)**

Comment: I only knew the wildcards and was googling using that keyword. Thanks for letting me know about `:contains`